# Java Retrofit multiple request one single response

Tags: java, android, retrofit

Hello guys I have an api endpoint that only takes one parameter "name":
https://api.xxxxx.com/v1/test/{name}/

I'm stuck on making a multiple request 
(e.g. https://api.xxxxx.com/v1/test/ALEX/ , https://api.xxxxx.com/v1/test/ELISA/,
https://api.xxxxx.com/v1/test/JOE/ )

I need to parse all the data from those 3 calls in a recyclerview, each request in a different row.

Is there anyway I can make the 3 request then get 1 JSON response only so I can parse it? What would be the best approach to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you have something like the following code in your retrofit api interface

```
@GET("v1/test/{name}/")
Observable<UserModel> getUserBy(@Path("name") name)
```

Then in your business logic you can call.

```
Observable.zip(retrofitApi.getUser("ALEX"), retrofitApi.getUser("ELISA"), retrofitApi.getUser("JOE"), (u1, u2, u3) -> {
  // prepare your returned users in a way suitable for further consumption
  // in this case I put them in a list
  return Arrays.asList(u1, u2, u3);
})
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
.subscribe( listOfUsers -> // TODO: do something with your users)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for the Observable and zip method.

Thank you

Comment: Can we do this using MVVM, without using RxJava?

Answer (score 0):

create an Interface like this

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/locations/add.json")
void sendMultipleLocations(@Query("token")String token, @FieldMap List<Map<String, String>> multipleLocations, Callback<String> callback);
```

and use  enqueue method of retrofit2 for asynchronously calling multiple request at the same time.This link will help you

https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1517